# How do I do a nginx url rewrite?

Tags: nginx

I'm new to ngnix, maybe my problem is trivial but I can't get any way to diagonize where is the issue :

We migrated our web app from version 0.6.4 to 0.6.5. To be sure, our users don't keep old files in their browser cache, we prefix our url with the version number to force refreshing : eg https://qa.share.place/**v0.6.5**/place/(:placeId)

So I need people who bookmarked a url with the old url format
https://qa.share.place/**v0.6.4**/place/(:placeId) to be redirected to the new url.

I attempted a url rewrite this way:

```
server {
    server_name qa.share.place;
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server ipv6only=on;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/qa.share.place/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/qa.share.place/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/qa.share.place/fullchain.pem;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl.conf;
    #https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,267685,267686
    #keepalive_timeout    70;

    root /home/ubuntu/share_place/bin/static;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    #return 302 https://www.share.place/upgrade;

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gunzip on;
    client_body_in_file_only clean;
    client_body_buffer_size 32K;

    sendfile off;
    send_timeout 300s;  
    client_max_body_size 1000M;


    #================ here is my issue
    rewrite ^(\/v0\.6\.4\/)(.*) /v0.6.5/$2 last;

    location /v0.6.5 {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/ ;
    }
  }
```

The issue, is that I have a 404, and I don't know how to log where the url was redirected (rewritten) to understand what's happening behind the wall.

Is the routing **location /v0.6.5 {}** still interpreted after the rewrite? or does the rewrite skip any treatments after it happens?

Any help please

Comment: Your `/0.6.5/$2` is missing a `v`. Is that a typo in the question or the cause of the problem?

Comment: Hi Richard, sorry for the delay, I had to find the time to test it. You're right there was a typo in the question, but I double checked the config now. It doesn't redirect (with the v in place: rewrite ^(\/v0\.6\.4\/)(.*) /v0.6.5/$2 last;). I corrected the question so there is no more typo

Comment: You may be getting browser cache issues, because you are not redirecting your users to the new URI. You may find `rewrite...permanent` works better than `rewrite...last`.

Comment: Actually I'm getting humain brain bug issues :) : the problem was that I tried with a url in the form .../0.6.4 and forgot to append a / after it sometimes.

Thanks a lot Richard

Comment: I changed the setting to   rewrite ^(\/v0\.6\.4)(.*) /v0.6.5$2 last; to include raw parameterless urls